# Cann't select specific field from DB using LinQ c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Actually I am using C# entity. I have added new Entity class for newly added table in .edmx file manually.The issue is can get all rows with all column from DB. But cann't select specific column using select new {}.
**actual error is Error CS0012  The type 'DbDataRecord' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxx'.**

This query working fine and it brings all the rows from DB

```
var listQuery = objReport.Batter_YTD_Tbl.ToList();
```

When i try like below throwing error

```
(from YTD_Tbl in objReport.Batter_YTD_Tbl 
 select new { test = YTD_Tbl.AB})
.ToList();
```

The error is

> Error   CS0012  The type 'DbDataRecord' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx'.   805AdminPortal.Reports  D:\xampp\htdocs\805\AdminSite-Starting-Code\805AdminPortal.Reports\Reports\PregameReport.cs 50  Active

Comment: I haven't use C# that much but to me this looks like it wants you to "import"/"use" the `System.Data` namespace

Comment: But i exisiting table seem getting no error. Only having issue for waht i added

Comment: Is the EDMX part in the same project (assembly)?  You added a a statement that activates a few more parts of Linq, I would just o with the advice from the error, add System.Data or find out what package you are missing

Comment: @davidg - the question here is for a large part _why_ that assembly is needed for 1 query and not for the other. And it isn't a done deal yet that this is about a missing dll. Edmax is more complicated.

Comment: @user8646340 - when adding the assy doesn't work, do come back and [edit] this question or open another.

Comment: @bommelding Yes, looks like a pretty good duplicate to me!

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need to add reference to `System.Data` , so do as below

Right click Reference and select Add Reference... In the window that comes up, select the assembly `System.Data`

Comment: and add `using System.Data;`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't see any benefit of doing that?

Comment: @DavidG: if OP needs to use classes in the `System.Data` namespace like `DbDataRecord` and doesn't want to write `System.Data.DbDataRecord`. Otherwise OP's next question might be _"type or namespace could not be found..."_

Comment: But it was added already

Comment: @TimSchmelter Well yes, but there's no suggestion that is happening here at all.

Comment: @user8646340 - not getting you if already added then you must be missing something else

Comment: @DavidG, @ timsSchmelter - have any of you ever used edmx?

Comment: @bommelding I'm using it right now (though I'd rather not...)